# mongo db dynamic query is formed in wrong way in php

Tags: php

I am using below php code for creating dynamic queries in mongo db like

```
        ..........
        if ($this->programId != "") {
          $query['classId'] = new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->programId);
        }
          
        ......
       
        $transportArrayCondition1 = ['transport_details' =>  ['$size' => 0]];
        $transportArrayCondition2 =   ['transport_details' =>  ['$elemMatch' =>  [
           '$or' => [
                    ['status' => ['$eq' => 'Requested']],
                    ['status' => ['$eq' => 'Active']],
            ],
            "approval_status" => "approved",
            "allotable" => "yes",
        ]]];

        $conditionToApply = '$or';

        if($this->routeId != "")
        {
          $transportArrayCondition1 = ['transport_details' => ['$gt' => ['$size' => 0]]];
          $transportArrayCondition2 =  ['transport_details' =>  ['$elemMatch' =>  [
            '$or' => [
              ['status' => ['$eq' => 'Requested']],
              ['status' => ['$eq' => 'Active']],
            ],
            "approval_status" => "approved",
            "allotable" => "yes",
            "route_id" =>  new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->routeId)
          ]]];

           $conditionToApply = '$and';
        }

        if ($this->stopId != "") 
        {
          $transportArrayCondition1 = ['transport_details' => ['$gt' => ['$size' => 0]]];
          $transportArrayCondition2 =  ['transport_details' =>  ['$elemMatch' =>  [
            '$or' => [
              ['status' => ['$eq' => 'Requested']],
              ['status' => ['$eq' => 'Active']],
            ],
            "approval_status" => "approved",
            "allotable" => "yes",
            "route_id" =>  new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->routeId),
            "stop_id" => $this->stopId
          ]]];

          $conditionToApply = '$and';
        }

      $query[$conditionToApply] = [$transportArrayCondition1, $transportArrayCondition2];

      if ($this->name != "") {

            $nameArray = ['$or' => [
              ['fullName' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('^' . $this->name, 'i')],
              ['firstLastName' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('^' . $this->name, 'i')],
              ['registration_temp_perm_no' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('^' . $this->name, 'i')],
            ]];

             array_push($query,$nameArray);
      }
```

Actually, I have put conditions in $query variables for MongoDB commands. I am failing to create condition in if '$this->name != "" ' part of the query. I am getting $query formed like

```
          {
"0": {
    "$or": [
        {
            "fullName": {
                "$regex": "^Vika",
                "$options": "i"
            }
        },
        {
            "firstLastName": {
                "$regex": "^Vika",
                "$options": "i"
            }
        },
        {
            "registration_temp_perm_no": {
                "$regex": "^Vika",
                "$options": "i"
            }
        }
    ]
},
"schoolId": {
    "$oid": "5f7aba204c610000670026d2"
},
"status": "Active",
"activeAcademicyearId": {
    "$oid": "5f7abaa54c61000067002738"
},
"$or": [
    {
        "transport_details": {
            "$size": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "transport_details": {
            "$elemMatch": {
                "$or": [
                    {
                        "status": {
                            "$eq": "Requested"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "status": {
                            "$eq": "Active"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "approval_status": "approved",
                "allotable": "yes"
            }
          }
          }
         ]
        }
```

What I actually want is

```
{
"$or": [
    {
        "fullName": {
            "$regex": "^Vika",
            "$options": "i"
        }
    },
    {
        "firstLastName": {
            "$regex": "^Vika",
            "$options": "i"
        }
    },
    {
        "registration_temp_perm_no": {
            "$regex": "^Vika",
            "$options": "i"
        }
    }
]
   "schoolId": {
    "$oid": "5f7aba204c610000670026d2"
  },
   "status": "Active",
   "activeAcademicyearId": {
    ............
```

I want array_push should add condition in $query like  "$or": [...]. It should not add condition like  "0": {"$or": [... ]}, I have tried a lot of things since morning but could not find any solution. Kindly help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$query` is associated array like structure and it already contains `$or` key in which you want to add the element you may need to update it as below.

Change `$nameArray` as below

```php
$nameArray = [
  ['fullName' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('^' . $this->name, 'i')],
  ['firstLastName' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('^' . $this->name, 'i')],
  ['registration_temp_perm_no' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('^' . $this->name, 'i')],
];
```

[`array_push`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) add elements add the end of the array

If you want to merge with existing `$or` values then we can use [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to merge both as array and then reassign it to existing `$or` key in `$query`

```php
$query['$or'] = array_merge($nameArray, $query['$or']);
```

Or

```php
$query['$or'] = $nameArray + $query['$or'];
```

If you want to replace then you can just reassign the changed `$nameArray` variable to `$query['$or']`

```
$query['$or'] = $nameArray;
```